# Solution of, an ODE related to the modified bessel equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, fluid-dynamics

I would like to know the general solution of
$$x^2 y^{''}+x y^{'} -k^2 x^2 y=0\tag{1}$$
for $y(x)$.

(1) is related to the equation
$$\quad x^2 y^{''}+x y^{'} - x^2 y=0$$
, which is the $n=0$ form of the modified Bessel equation

$$x^2 y^{''}+x y^{'} -( x^2+n^2) y=0$$

Other Information.

The material of this question turns up in fluid mechanics, in the theory of the instability of jets.

There is plenty of material on Wikipedia about the Bessel and related equations but I have not found there, the general solution I am looking for.

Comment: I did search on stack exchange but did not find the question mentioned by xanonec.

Comment: The question mentioned by xanonec has the general solution I was looking for, along with a proof of it.